# Use DispatcherTimer with Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, dispatcher

Why my DispatcherTimer don't work with Windows Service .

The purpose behind that i want use DispatcherTimer for check a windows service License

```
    public OIMService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("OIM_Log"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("OIM_Log", "OIMLog");
        }
        EventLog.Source = "OIM_Log";
        EventLog.Log = "OIMLog";
        _helpers = new ValidationHelpers();
        StartTimer();

    }


protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

    if (_helpers.IsValid())
    {
        ConfigureServer();
        StartTimer();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Stop();
    }


}



 private void StartTimer()
        {
            const int time = 10;
            _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimerTick);
            _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(time));
            _dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = true;
            _dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
    private void DispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EventLog.WriteEntry("test test test ...");
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The point of `DispatcherTimer` is to fire its `Tick` event on the dispatcher thread. That's important because you can only manipulate Silverlight/WPF UI elements on the dispatcher thread. In a Windows Service, there *is* no dispatcher thread... there's no UI to manipulate. Why would you want to use a `DispatcherTimer` instead of (say) [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)?

Comment: i want to use DispatcherTimer to check for windows Service license every day

Comment: @tito11: And why do you think DispatcherTimer is the most suitable timer to use for that, when you don't have a UI?